# SVG Word wrapping function in PHP?

Tags: php, svg, word-wrap

Before I go ahead and try to code my own, are there any functions / libraries for PHP which will generate SVG images with text wrapped to a bounding box?

I'm looking for a function which will accept a string and a bonding box, along the lines of: `wrapText($text,$x,$y,$width)`

So if `$text` were "The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog" and `$width` were 125, the SVG file might show:

> The Quick Brown
>   Fox Jumped
>   Over The Lazy
>   Dog.

[This XML.com article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/09/11/quint.html) looks like what I'd use, but it's ECMAScript built into the SVG. I'm looking for something that generates pure SVG with no scripts (so it could be read by Adobe Illustrator, for example)

Before I re-code their algorithm in PHP, does anything like this already exist?

Comment: Well, even if it sounds a bit as an overkill, you could use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) to generate a trivial graph (one node only).

Comment: I end up just writing my own algorithm from scratch in PHP, largely based on the xml.com article. If anyone has any better solutions please post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did this myself. The final result is proprietary code, so I can't share it here. But basically it involved creating an SVG 1.2 document with the text inside a `<flowRect>`, and then feeding that SVG through [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) to convert the SVG 1.2 `<flowRect>` to a series of SVG 1.1 `<tspan>`s